# GeoServer sub-pages and OWS service only for those logged-in

Tags: geoserver, ows

I am trying to edit source files of GeoServer to meet my project requirements. I want to make newly added OWS services (like "org.geoserver.hello" example) and some of the sub-pages (like "helloweb" example) accessible only for logged-in users.

Is there an example, source file or documentation page (apart from http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.x/en/user/security/index.html and http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/security/index.html) I could rely on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. To make particular ows service protected its option in the tab security/services (main webpage, accessible for admin) must be set for `"ROLE_AUTHENTICATED"`. As for a subpage, we must edit applicationContext.xml in order to add

```
<property name="authorizer" ref="workspaceAdminAuthorizer"/>
```

where `property id` is pointing to our subpage.